# How to allow peers access only to the Internet?

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I tried for a long time to find the answer to the question "How to allow peers access only to the Internet?", But I did not find anything. The only thing I understood is that this can be done through iptables.

> Internet-only access means no other peers can be accessed by other peers

At the monent, it's my wireguard config -

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51830
PrivateKey = <private_key>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Insert* a rule that drops "loopback" forwarding between the wireguard interface:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j DROP
```

By the way, `ACCEPT` rules like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
```

is unnecessary unless you have `-P FORWARD DROP` somewhere or general `DROP` rules that follows. (If any of those is the case then your `ACCEPT` rule should be insufficient on its own.)

Note: for the difference between `-I` and `-A`, or the meaning of `-P`, please refer to [the man page of `iptables`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html). Long story short, rule order matters in iptables (or actually, firewalling / {black,white}listing in general). Each of the tables (`filter`, `nat`, ...) has its own order though. (And order mostly matters in `filter`.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the Wireguard setting of
`AllowedIPs` ([Peer] config section).

This is the set of IP addresses the local host should route to the
remote peer through the WireGuard tunnel.
This setting tells the local host what goes in tunnel.

Example:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.21.199.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

For more information see these sources:

- [What does WireGuard AllowedIPs actually do?](https://techoverflow.net/2021/07/09/what-does-wireguard-allowedips-actually-do/)
- [What is the difference between Endpoint and AllowedIPs fields in Wireguard config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444747/what-is-the-difference-between-endpoint-and-allowedips-fields-in-wireguard-confi)

Comment: As far as I understand, AllowedIP is the ip that connected to the client through this peer. Accordingly, if peer A has AllowedIP = 10.0.0.2, and peer B has AllowedIP = 10.0.0.3, then when ping with a connection to peer A at ip address 10.0.0.3 there will be an answer, which means peer B answers peer A. And I need it not to be.

Comment: See the poster's config in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050136/wireguard-client-communication-without-peer-key-via-1-router-server) where he unintentionally blocked pings between clients using `AllowedIPs `.